# How can I get the data with using url parameter in a Laravel application using VueJS and Vue-router

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios, vue-router

I'm making an application with a list page and the detail page(Item.vue) simply.
From the list, a user can go to the detail page with the url like localhost/item/12345.
But I cannot make the logic for my Laravel application with VueJS and Vue-router.

Laravel 5.4,

node 6.11, npm 3.10.10,

axios 0.15.3, vue 2.3.4, vue-router 2.6.0

My code is like below

**Example.vue (using as a list page)**

```
<template>
 <p class="card-text"><router-link v-bind:to="{ name:'item', params:{ id: item.id }}">
  {{ item.title }}</router-link>
 </p>
</template>
<script>
 export default {
  data(){
   return{
    $item:[]
   }
  },
  mounted(){
   var self = this;
   axios.get('/item').then(function(response){
    return self.item = response.data;
   });
  }
 }
</script>
```

**Item.vue**

```
<template>
 <p class="card-text">{{item.title}}</p>
 <p class="card-text">{{item.content}}</p>
</template>
<script>
 export default {
  data(){
   return{
    $item:[]
   }
  },
  mounted(){
   var self = this;
   axios.get('/item'+this.$route.params.slug
   ).then(function(response){
    return self.item = response.data;
   });
  }
 }
</script>
```

**routes.js**

```
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
var routes=[
 {
  name:'item',
  path:'/item/:id',
  component:require('./components/Item.vue'),
  props: true
 }
];
export default new VueRouter({
 routes
});
```

**routes/web.js**

```
Route::resource('item','ItemController');
Route::resource('item/{id}', 'ItemController@show');
```

**ItemController**

```
<?php
 namespace App\Http\Controllers;
 use Illuminate\Http\Request;
 use App\Items;

 class ItemController extends Controller
 {
  public function index()
  {
   return Items::all();
  }
  public function show($id)
  {
   $item = Items::where('id', '=', $id)->firstOrFail();
   return view('item.show', compact('item'));
  }
 }
```

**app.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import router from './routes.js';

require('./bootstrap');
window.Vue = require('vue');
Vue.use(VueRouter);

Vue.component('example', require('./components/Example.vue'));
const app = new Vue({
 router,
 el: '#app'
});
```

**the warning message is shown for the list page**

```
[Vue warn]: Property or method "item" is not defined on the instance but referenced 
during render. Make sure to declare reactive data properties in the data option.
found in
---> <Item> at /var/www/laravel/resources/assets/js/components/Item.vue
 <Root>
```

**the error message for the detail page**

```
Error: Request failed with status code 500
```

Comment: error is in ```Item.vue``` please edit your question and add this file code too

Comment: sorry, I fixed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, if you check errors:

> Property or method "item" is not defined

and check `item` in your data code:

```
  data(){
   return{
    $item:[]
   }
  },
```

you define item with $ but you use item variable without $

In Javascript you dont need to define variable with dollar symbol

change it to item in both `item.vue` and `example.vue`:

```
  data(){
   return{
    item:[]
   }
  },
```

Secondly:
check `axios` code:

```
axios.get('/item'+this.$route.params.slug
```

it means call route `/itemslug` with get method
but I dont see a route define like this in router but if you put / after item like this:

```
axios.get('/item/'+this.$route.params.slug
```

it will change your get url to : `/item/slug`

but you dont using slug in your controller to return view
you sould change your controller to :

```
  public function show($slug)
  {
   $item = Items::where('slug', '=', $slug)->firstOrFail();
   return view('item.show', compact('item'));
  }
```

or change `this.$route.params.slug` to `this.$route.params.id`

on the other hand
in your controller

```
  public function show($id)
  {
   $item = Items::where('id', '=', $id)->firstOrFail();
   return view('item.show', compact('item'));
  }
```

as you see show method return collection to item.show view, if you want to get data directly with axios you shouldnd return view instead of you can do this

```
  public function show($id)
  {
   return $item = Items::where('id', '=', $id)->firstOrFail();
  }
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. My program is much better now without the error.

Comment: But {{item}} in Item.vue has no data instead of I could get a data from database and could confirmed the data on console for axios.get(
                '/item/' + this.$route.params.asin
            ).then(function(response){
                console.log(response.data);
                return self.item = response.data;
            });